# Explicitly hold left mouse click down on "X" button

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to be able to problematically explicitly click the left mouse button on "X" of a process and hold for an interval of seconds. Any guidance will be appreciated. I do not ask for full code but a starting point.

Comment: Do you mean the `X` in the top right of the window (i.e. the thing you click to close an app down)? Why do you want to **hold it down**?

Comment: Do you specifically want to click the mouse button the the 'X', or do you just want to close the application? I take it you're talking about a process other than your program?

Comment: Please read about the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). This one probably is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could first send message [`WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-gettitlebarinfoex) to the window of the process, to get the RECT of the 'X' button, then use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) send the `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` at the RECT in the 'X' button area and set delay for the holding time. Before you send mouse input, you'd better make sure the 'X' button is visible on the screen. Finally, send `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP`.

Comment: [When you synthesize input with SendInput, you are also synthesizing the timestamp](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121101-00/?p=6193): *"The `time` field in the `MOUSE­INPUT` structure is not for introducing delays in playback."*

Comment: @IInspectable Oh, you're right! Sorry for misunderstanding the document and thanks for point out. I corrected it.